# Load external javascript file where document.write is used

Tags: javascript, document.write

i'm trying add external javascript code with this code:

```
function get_js(b){
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = b;
head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

This external javascript code using document.write inside:

```
document.write('<script language="JavaScript">document.write(\'<div id="something" style="position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;">&nbsp;<\/div>\');...
```

When i'm trying execute function from this file, i'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: some_function is not defined
```

I thought that document.write in JS code is problem. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

///

OK, figured it out with POSTSCRIBE: https://github.com/krux/postscribe

Comment: You should avoid document.write altogether: http://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/3299157

Comment: Yes i know, but this is 3rd party script.

Answer (score 2):

don't use `document.write()`. If you call `document.write()` after the page is load, it will "reopen" the pageload and as a sideeffect clear everything from the screen.

take a look at properties/methods like `innerHTML`, `textContent`, `document.createElement()`, `appendChild()`, ...